# Assign Role to Anonymous session

Tags: asp.net, webforms, roleprovider

Our site uses the ASP Role and Membership provider system for Forms authentication. We have organized our files into folders which enforce an Authorization list via a folder web.config document (eg: you must have the Admin role to access pages in the ~/Admin folder) and we do not allow anonymous (not logged in) access except in the site root. Site is hosted on IIS7.5 with .Net 4.0 bindings and scriptmaps.

Stakeholders are now asking that we allow PINs to authenticate for specific usecases, where the user does not yet have credentials, but has recieved a letter with a PIN.

We wrote a stack to validate PINs for authentication, but we don't have a way to tell they membership/role API that they are now a logged in user, since they are bypassing our SSO by using a PIN.

I need to find a way to assign a role temporarily to an anonymous session when the operator presents a valid pin, so that they can then make use of the pages in folders that  would not otherwise allow anonymous access.

I've seen indications that you can tie profile info to an anonymous user but I've been unable to find any info about assigning the user (session really) a role.

Does anyone have any ideas for assigning a role to an anonymous user so they can navigate past authorization lists requiring a specific role?

Comment: when you enter PIN, you're still an authenticated user, but may be with different role than usual, I'm not sure why you want to treat that user as anonymous

Comment: to clarify I don't WANT to treat them as anonymous; IIS treats them as anonymous, because they have not logged in. I want to treat them as logged in, even though they have not logged in via Forms Authentication. I need `Request.IsAuthenticated()` to return true, and `Membership.IsInRole(somerole)` to also return true, but without them having logged in (except for the pin, which .Net doesn't recognize as a login).

Answer (score 1):

Try extending `ClaimsAuthenticationManager`. You can override `Authenticate`. This should allow you to treat treat your PIN users as authenticated, and allow you to assign roles.

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : ClaimsAuthenticationManager
{
    public override ClaimsPrincipal Authenticate(string resourceName, ClaimsPrincipal incomingPrincipal)
    {...
```

You can activate your extended `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` in `Global.asax.cs` (or `.vb`). This example is from an ASP.NET MVC application. (You didn't mention whether you were using MVC or WebForms.)

```
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    ...

    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest()
    {
        var principal = ClaimsPrincipal.Current;
        var transformer = new ClaimsTransformer();

        var newPrincipal = transformer.Authenticate(string.Empty, principal);

        Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newPrincipal;
        HttpContext.Current.User = newPrincipal;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I am using WebForms, and from what I'm seeing the Windows Identity Framework that contains the `ClaimsAuthenticationManager` started with .Net 4.5. we're still on 4.0, so are there any tweaks to make it work without framework 4.5? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748497.aspx

Comment: Maybe, but I don't know them. I've heard that Claims Authentication was partly implemented in 4.0, but I haven't tried it. In 4.5, roles are claims, so I assumed you were using Claims Authentication. If you are, and if upgrading is an option in your situation, you might find it well worth your while.

Comment: actually, our SSO itself is using .Net 2.0, but client applications can be 2/3.x/4.x (or really any version that supports `System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider`). Anyway, thanks for your response. if you have any epiphanies, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Frank,

Here is a piece of code I used at a company I no longer work for.

First, here is a list of constants and private variables:

```
private const int LOGON_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
private const int LOGON_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;
private const string m_domain = "PLACE YOUR ACTIVE DIRECTORY DOMAIN NAME HERE";
private const string m_sUser = "PLACE YOUR ADMINISTRATOR ACCOUNT'S USERNAME HERE";
private const string m_sPassword = "PLACE YOUR m_sUser PASSWORD HERE";
private static string m_lastUser = null;
private static DirectoryEntry m_rootDir;
private WindowsImpersonationContext m_impersonatedUser;
public enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL {
  SecurityAnonymous = 0,
  SecurityIdentification = 1,
  SecurityImpersonation = 2,
  SecurityDelegation = 3
}
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)] // obtains user token
private static extern bool LogonUser(string pszUsername, string pszDomain, string pszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider, ref IntPtr phToken);
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)] // closes open handes returned by LogonUser
private extern static bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)] // creates duplicate token handle
private extern static bool DuplicateToken(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, int SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);
```

All of these are used in the meat of my class, **Impersonate**, which makes any Windows account impersonate **m_sUser**:

```
private void Impersonate() {
  IntPtr pExistingTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
  IntPtr pDuplicateTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
  m_lastUser = Environment.UserName;
  bool bImpersonated = LogonUser(m_sUser, m_domain, m_sPassword, LOGON_LOGON_INTERACTIVE, LOGON_PROVIDER_DEFAULT, ref pExistingTokenHandle);
  if (bImpersonated) {
    try {
      bool bRetVal = DuplicateToken(pExistingTokenHandle, (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityImpersonation, ref pDuplicateTokenHandle);
      if (bRetVal) { // create new identity using new primary token
        using (var newId = new WindowsIdentity(pDuplicateTokenHandle)) {
          m_impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate();
          m_rootDir = new DirectoryEntry(m_ldapPath);
        }
      } else { // did DuplicateToken fail?
        int nErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
        string sResult = "DuplicateToken() failed with error code: " + nErrorCode + GSTR.CRLF;
        MessageBox.Show(sResult, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
    } catch (Exception err) {
      MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "ADWrapper Error");
    } finally {
      m_working = false;
      if (!pDuplicateTokenHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) {
        CloseHandle(pDuplicateTokenHandle);
        pDuplicateTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
      }
      if (!pExistingTokenHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) {
        CloseHandle(pExistingTokenHandle); // close existing handle
        pExistingTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
      }
    }
  } else {
    int nErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
    string sResult = "LogonUser() failed with error code: " + nErrorCode + GSTR.CRLF;
    MessageBox.Show(sResult, "Login Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
  }
}
```

It was running on .NET Framework 2.0 when I first got there, but it moved up to .NET 4.0 before I left.

I used this with a static account that was setup as an administrator on our network, but you could probably see how to modify this to work with authenticating a user with some user name with your PIN.

Don't forget to call the `Dispose()` method below to Revert back to the default user. If the class that contains this code implements **IDisposable**, you've got a good chance at this getting called by the GC if you forget:

```
public void Revert() {
  if (m_impersonatedUser != null) {
    m_impersonatedUser.Undo();
    m_impersonatedUser = null;
  }
  if (m_rootDir != null) {
    m_rootDir.Close();
    Global.Dispose(m_rootDir);
    m_rootDir = null;
  }
}

public void Dispose() {
  Revert();
}
```

Again, I don't work at that company anymore, so I can't test particular items for you or tell you what kind of values are returned for specific scenarios.

I hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: that some slick code, but I do have a few concerns about it in a multi-user multithread environment like IIS. have you used this code as part of a web application, where many users might be impersonating the same user simultaneously?

Comment: It was a Windows Forms application, and had perhaps 100 users running it at any one time. It should not matter that AD sees your admin account logged in multiple times. Think about logging into your PC, and then walk to the PC next to yours and log in on it as well. AD does not care how many times you are logged in.